# How to make a github workflow error message show up in log and annotations?

Tags: github-actions

I have a workflow step that runs this last stage of a shell command in a loop:

`|| echo "::error Filename $filename doesn't match possible files" && exit 1 ; done`

The exit is triggered appropriately, but the only annotation I see is:

Error: Process completed with exit code 1.

The log shows the entire shell command pipeline and also that same error message, but not my echo'd error.

How do I get my output, including the $filename variable, included?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have wrong syntax:

`echo "::error::Filename $filename doesn't match possible files"`

You need to postfix `error` with `::`

Here is a working example of [workflow](https://github.com/grzegorzkrukowski/stackoverflow_tests/blob/main/.github/workflows/71087094.yml) using my suggestion:
https://github.com/grzegorzkrukowski/stackoverflow_tests/actions/runs/1835152772

There must be something else wrong with your workflow if it doesn't work - other command is exiting with code 1 before it has a chance to execute.

Comment: Hmm -- I just tried making this modification and it doesn't appear to have changed anything. I tried it both with a space between ::error:: and Filename, and without a space. Neither variation showed the error in the annotations or the log. All I get is the message saying "Process completed with exit code 1"

Comment: I also tried this variation: 
    
echo "::error file=$filename::$filename doesn't match possible files" && exit 1 ; done


Is there better documentation than what's available here? I don't see which fields are optional vs. mandatory. I thought maybe the file was required, but that didn't solve it.

https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-commands-for-github-actions#setting-an-error-message

Comment: That's definitely the correct syntax, I am using it personally a lot for example here:
https://github.com/raycast/github-actions/blob/master/ray-cli/ray_cli.sh#L63-L64

Maybe try separating exit 1 into a different line ? 
The stuff you can find in link above works for sure - I am using it for ages.

Also maybe there is something else failing before this executes ? Can you show full workflow and example run ?

Comment: @JamesWetterau I updated my answer with working example, proving that my answer works - there must be something else failing in your workflow.
You can submit new question with showing us full workflow

Comment: It was a shell scripting error! The 

```foo || echo "::error::..." && exit 1 ```

Was reaching exit 1 because foo was succeeding. I needed to both fix the foo part of the pipeline and wrap the second part in { }'s, e.g.

```foo || { echo "::error::..." && exit 1 }```

Comment: @JamesWetterau that's why it's important to always put full code to your questions, because sometimes problem may be somewhere else :) I hope at least ensuring you on ::error:: part helped a bit ;)